# How to implement gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I was trying to look for example of gallery in the net, but luckily I found my previous work. However, when I opened my main activity, it said that "Gallery" is deprecated, and I found out that it was deprecated since API 16. I wonder if there is an alternative in doing the image gallery. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewPager or HorizontalScrollView

Here is a tutorial with the HorizontalScrollView

http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html

Comment: Thanks! But I have a question. I would like the gallery to be somewhere in the middle, and when the users click an image, the image will be displayed above the gallery?

Comment: Then you have to add an OnClickListener to your ImageViews.

Comment: @MiguelRivera follow the tutorial, then try to customize it by your own: in the end you will learn more and more!

Comment: I downloaded the code, and there is an error, and points to this line, "File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
                 
        File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
        for (File file : files){
         myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(file.getAbsolutePath()));"

any ideas?